# Can I define a function in the function namespace by it's value?

Tags: common-lisp

I recently started to learn CL, and I'm trying to figure out if I can set a value to a symbol in the function namespace.

I'd like to just define functions in terms of function composition, or simply by an existing function (e.g. I just had to rewrite `identity` twice  in a toy "Hello, World!" level project). I'm not sure if it's even possible since it might break the namespace separation (at least without enforcement). I also tried to `macroexpand` what `defun` actually does; it's too cryptic to me as a beginner but it seems like the core part of it is built-in (I'm using SBCL).

So e.g. instead of saying:

```
(defun myfn (x) x)
```

I'd rather just say:

```
(def..? myfn identity)
```

If I can't do that, how can I avoid this class of code duplication? (which includes functions created by function composition, not just creating synonyms).

Comment: Just an idea, you could add a macro which expands to `(defun myfun (&rest args) (apply identity args))`. Of course, in a Lisp-1, you could just `(define myfn identity)`.

Comment: Be sure to have a look at some of the functions linked from the duplicate, too.  There's lots of useful information floating around. The one titled **why defun is not the same as (setq <name> <lambda>)?** has some good discussion.

Comment: Also, just to be clear, you can get the function value of a symbol using the `#'` notation.  I.e., you don't need to do `(let ((id (lambda (x) x))) (compose id ...))`.  You can just do `(let ((id #'identity)) (compose id ...))` or `(compose #'identity ...)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's possible for functions bound to symbols, in the current *environment*:

```
(setf (symbol-function 'myfn) #'identity)
```

There is also `(setf FDEFINTION)` which does mostly the same, but also supports `setf` functions.

One can't do it for lexically bound functions (by `FLET` and `LABELS`).

**Example how to set a symbol function using `(setf fdefinition)`**

```
CL-USER 11 > (setf (fdefinition 'myfn) #'identity)
#<Function IDENTITY 410003F974>

CL-USER 12 > (myfn 10)
10
```

**Further remarks**

Note that it does that in the current environment. Thus

```
(defun myfn (x) x)
```

might be replaced by something like

```
(eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute)
  (setf (fdefinition 'myfn) #'identity))
```

Tha advantage: the function would be known as usual during compilation.

One of the things to keep in mind:

The symbol object may carry some information. For example the original function name, if there was one:

```
CL-USER 13 > #'identity
#<Function IDENTITY 410003F974>
```

Setting the function cell of a symbol, does not change that:

```
CL-USER 14 > #'myfn
#<Function IDENTITY 410003F974>
```

It's the same function object with its original internal name. One may be able to access that name, but one can't change it:

```
CL-USER 18 > (nth-value 2 (function-lambda-expression #'identity))
IDENTITY
```

There is also a problem with self-recursive functions:

```
CL-USER 19 > (defun foo (n)
               (if (zerop n)
                   1
                 (* n (foo (1- n)))))  ; here foo calls the function foo
FOO
```

now we set `BAR` to use the function `FOO`

```
CL-USER 20 > (setf (symbol-function 'bar) #'foo)
#<interpreted function FOO 4060004084>


CL-USER 21 > (bar 10)
3628800
```

Here we redefine `FOO`:

```
CL-USER 22 > (defun foo (n)
               (if (zerop n)
                   1
                 (+ n (foo (1- n)))))
FOO
```

`BAR` still uses the old `FOO`, which may or may not call the new `FOO`.

```
CL-USER 23 > (bar 10)
460
```

OOPS! We changed FOO, but it has strange effects on BAR: the first iteration is the old FOO and the next recursive invocation is the new FOO.

`BAR` and `FOO` are two different versions of the same function. But both call the function `FOO`, which may be the old or the new function - depending on how you interpret or compile the code.

```
CL-USER 24 > #'foo
#<interpreted function FOO 40600041F4>

CL-USER 25 > #'bar
#<interpreted function FOO 4060004084>
```